# The server failed to resume the transaction issue when executing Spring batch job in multi-theaded mode

Tags: sql-server, spring-boot, multithreading, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch

I am developing Spring Boot 3.x application with Spring Batch 5.1.1, Spring Data JPA, Hibernate,  Microsoft SQL server, Gradle, JDK 17. Especially, batch job reads items from flat file, processes them and writes to database(inserts new records or updates existing). Multiple parts can be bound to same part details.

*Entity mappings:*

- **PartDetails** entity

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@Audited
@Entity
@Table(name = "part_details")
public class PartDetails {

    @Column(name = "part_number", unique = true)
    @Id
    private String partNumber;
    private String description;
    ...
}
```

- **Part** entity

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@Audited
@Entity
@Table(name = "part")
public class Part {

    private String partNumber;
    private String partStatus;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "factory_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    private Factory factory;

    ...

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "part_details_id")
    private PartDetails partDetails;

}
```

*Entity repositories:*

- **PartRepository**

```java
@Repository
public interface PartRepository extends JpaRepository<Part, Long> {

    Part findByPartNumberAndFactoryCode(String partNumber, Integer factoryCode);

    ...

}
```

- **PartDetailsRepository**

```java
@Repository
public interface PartDetailsRepository extends JpaRepository<PartDetails, String> {

    PartDetails findByPartNumber(String partNumber);

}
```

*Spring Batch Item Processor:*

**PartProcessor**

```java
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class PartProcessor implements ItemProcessor<ExternalPart, Part> {

    private final PartRepository partRepository;
    private final FactoryRepository factoryRepository;
    private final PartDetailsRepository partDetailsRepository;

    @Override
    public Part process(ExternalPart item) {
        Integer factoryCode = Integer.parseInt(item.getFactory());
        String partNumber = item.getArticleNumber();
        Part part = partRepository.findByPartNumberAndFactoryCode(partNumber, factoryCode);

        if (part == null) {
            part = new Part();

            Factory factory = factoryRepository.findByCode(factoryCode);

            if (factory == null) {
                log.error("Unknown factory code {} received. Ignoring this {} article number",
                        item.getFactory(), item.getArticleNumber());

                return null;
            }

            part.setFactory(factory);
            part.setPartNumber(partNumber);
            part.setPartStatus(StringUtils.EMPTY);
        }

        PartDetails partDetails = partDetailsRepository.findByPartNumber(partNumber);

        part.setPctPartsDetail(partDetails);

        return part;
    }
}
```

*Batch configuration:*

**PartsBatchConfiguration**

```java
@Configuration
public class PartsBatchConfiguration {


    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public SynchronizedItemStreamReader<ExternalPart> reader() {
        ...
    }

    @Bean
    public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();

        taskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(6);
        taskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(8);
        taskExecutor.setQueueCapacity(10);
        taskExecutor.setThreadNamePrefix("parts-");

        return taskExecutor;
    }

    @Bean
    public RepositoryItemWriter<Part> writer(PartRepository partsRepository) {
        RepositoryItemWriter<Part> writer = new RepositoryItemWriter<>();
        writer.setRepository(partsRepository);
        return writer;
    }

    @Bean
    public Job job(Step step, JobRepository jobRepository) {
        return new JobBuilder("importParts", jobRepository)
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .flow(step)
                .end()
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step(SynchronizedItemStreamReader<ExternalPart> reader, JobRepository jobRepository,
                          PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager,
                          ItemProcessor<ExternalPart, Part> processor,
                          RepositoryItemWriter<Part> writer) {
        return new StepBuilder("partStep", jobRepository)
                .<ExternalPart, Part>chunk(500, transactionManager)
                .reader(reader)
                .processor(processor)
                .writer(writer)
                .taskExecutor(taskExecutor())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemProcessor<ExternalPart, Part> processor(PartRepository partsRepository,
                                                           FactoryRepository factoryRepository,
                                                           PartDetailsRepository partDetailsRepository) {
        return new PartsProcessor(partsRepository, factoryRepository, partDetailsRepository);
    }

}
```

*Gradle build file:*

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.2.3'
}

apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

group 'my.parts'
version = '1.0'

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:2023.0.0"
    }
}

// other variables
def lombokVersion = '1.18.30'

dependencies {

    // spring
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-batch'

    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-openfeign'

    implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui:2.3.0'

    // db
    runtimeOnly 'com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc'
    implementation 'org.hibernate:hibernate-envers:6.4.3.Final'

    // other libs
    implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi:5.2.5'
    implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:5.2.5'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.14.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.4'
    implementation 'io.github.openfeign:feign-okhttp:13.1'
    annotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok:$lombokVersion"

    // tests
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-test'
    testAnnotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok:$lombokVersion"
    testCompileOnly "org.projectlombok:lombok:$lombokVersion"
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

When I am triggering batch job execution with multiple threads task executor (as it was provided in my application details) I am facing following error:

```
2024-03-07T15:43:18.296+02:00  WARN 22487 --- [        parts-4] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 3971, SQLState: S0001
2024-03-07T15:43:18.296+02:00 ERROR 22487 --- [        parts-4] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : The server failed to resume the transaction. Desc:4300000001.
2024-03-07T15:43:18.299+02:00  INFO 22487 --- [        parts-4] o.h.e.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener  : HHH000327: Error performing load command

org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: JDBC exception executing SQL [select pd1_0.part_number,pd1_0.created_at,pd1_0.created_by,pd1_0.desc_english,pd1_0.desc_swedish,pd1_0.part_color,pd1_0.part_sort,pd1_0.part_type,pd1_0.updated_at,pd1_0.updated_by,pd1_0.weight from part_details pd1_0 where pd1_0.part_number=?] [The server failed to resume the transaction. Desc:4300000001.] [n/a]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:91) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:58) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:108) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:94) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.DeferredResultSetAccess.executeQuery(DeferredResultSetAccess.java:265) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.DeferredResultSetAccess.getResultSet(DeferredResultSetAccess.java:167) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.JdbcValuesResultSetImpl.advanceNext(JdbcValuesResultSetImpl.java:218) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.JdbcValuesResultSetImpl.processNext(JdbcValuesResultSetImpl.java:98) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.AbstractJdbcValues.next(AbstractJdbcValues.java:19) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.internal.RowProcessingStateStandardImpl.next(RowProcessingStateStandardImpl.java:66) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.spi.ListResultsConsumer.consume(ListResultsConsumer.java:187) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.spi.ListResultsConsumer.consume(ListResultsConsumer.java:33) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.doExecuteQuery(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:209) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.executeQuery(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:83) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.spi.JdbcSelectExecutor.list(JdbcSelectExecutor.java:76) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.spi.JdbcSelectExecutor.list(JdbcSelectExecutor.java:65) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.SingleIdLoadPlan.load(SingleIdLoadPlan.java:145) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.SingleIdLoadPlan.load(SingleIdLoadPlan.java:117) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.ast.internal.SingleIdEntityLoaderStandardImpl.load(SingleIdEntityLoaderStandardImpl.java:75) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.doLoad(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3748) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3737) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:604) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromCacheOrDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:590) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:560) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:544) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:207) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadWithRegularProxy(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:290) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:242) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:111) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:68) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:138) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoadNoChecks(SessionImpl.java:1222) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1068) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.graph.entity.internal.EntitySelectFetchInitializer.initializeInstance(EntitySelectFetchInitializer.java:195) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.internal.InitializersList.initializeInstance(InitializersList.java:70) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.internal.StandardRowReader.coordinateInitializers(StandardRowReader.java:109) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.internal.StandardRowReader.readRow(StandardRowReader.java:86) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.spi.ListResultsConsumer.consume(ListResultsConsumer.java:203) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.spi.ListResultsConsumer.consume(ListResultsConsumer.java:33) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.doExecuteQuery(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:209) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.executeQuery(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:83) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.spi.JdbcSelectExecutor.list(JdbcSelectExecutor.java:76) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.spi.JdbcSelectExecutor.list(JdbcSelectExecutor.java:65) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.lambda$new$2(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:137) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.withCacheableSqmInterpretation(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:362) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.performList(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:303) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.QuerySqmImpl.doList(QuerySqmImpl.java:509) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.spi.AbstractSelectionQuery.list(AbstractSelectionQuery.java:427) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.spi.AbstractSelectionQuery.getSingleResult(AbstractSelectionQuery.java:564) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$SingleEntityExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:223) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:92) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:149) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:137) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:170) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:158) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:164) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:143) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:70) ~[spring-data-commons-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:385) ~[spring-tx-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:135) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:220) ~[spring-aop-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy194.findByPartNumberAndFactoryCode(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at my.parts.processor.PartsProcessor.process(PartsProcessor.java:32) ~[main/:na]
    at my.parts.processor.PartsProcessor.process(PartsProcessor.java:17) ~[main/:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.doProcess(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:146) ~[spring-batch-core-5.1.1.jar:5.1.1]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.transform(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:322) ~[spring-batch-core-5.1.1.jar:5.1.1]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.process(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:220) ~[spring-batch-core-5.1.1.jar:5.1.1]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:75) ~[spring-batch-core-5.1.1.jar:5.1.1]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:388) ~[spring-batch-core-5.1.1.jar:5.1.1]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:312) ~[spring-batch-core-5.1.1.jar:5.1.1]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140) ~[spring-tx-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:255) ~[spring-batch-core-5.1.1.jar:5.1.1]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:82) ~[spring-batch-core-5.1.1.jar:5.1.1]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.TaskExecutorRepeatTemplate$ExecutingRunnable.run(TaskExecutorRepeatTemplate.java:261) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-5.1.1.jar:5.1.1]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840) ~[na:na]
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The server failed to resume the transaction. Desc:4300000001.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:259) ~[mssql-jdbc-12.4.2.jre11.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1695) ~[mssql-jdbc-12.4.2.jre11.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:648) ~[mssql-jdbc-12.4.2.jre11.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:567) ~[mssql-jdbc-12.4.2.jre11.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7675) ~[mssql-jdbc-12.4.2.jre11.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:4137) ~[mssql-jdbc-12.4.2.jre11.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:272) ~[mssql-jdbc-12.4.2.jre11.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:246) ~[mssql-jdbc-12.4.2.jre11.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeQuery(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:485) ~[mssql-jdbc-12.4.2.jre11.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.DeferredResultSetAccess.executeQuery(DeferredResultSetAccess.java:246) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    ... 82 common frames omitted
```

Batch works fine in case of removal of task executor and running it in single thread mode.

I suppose, there is some concurrency issue somewhere in libraries or I missed something to configure in my application. Because this looks like instance field/variable mixin.

Can anybody assist with this, provide any ideas or advices?

Comment: Perhaps this might enlighten you: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/the-server-failed-to-resume-the-transaction-why/ba-p/383530 I'm guessing there's some deadlock or other error going on which is getting masked by the transaction one

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Unfortunately, I did not found how to resolve it.